# github API,How to get any users stargazer count history by date

Tags: github-api

How to get a users stargaze historical data.number of stars he got for a particular day, or a list of stars get by date, by week etc. thanks..

Comment: 'stars he got for a particular day' is a bit vague because a user 'stars' a repository. Are you looking to see how many people (over time) are following a particular user, how many people starred a repository, or how many repositories a specific user starred?